# Can get tokens, but receive neither push nor silent notifications

Tags: c#, ios, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

On March 9 or so, I was receiving both push and silent notifications, but on March 22 or so, I stopped receiving tokens and silent notifications.
When I created a new project and implemented FCM, I am still not receiving either push or silent notifications, although I can get the tokens.

Has anyone else experienced the same symptoms and solved the problem?

version
iPad 15.4.1
Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging 8.10.0

The library in 4.7.1 was receiving push notifications but not silent notifications; after updating to 8.10.0, both push and silent notifications are no longer being received.

```
public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
{
      Console.WriteLine(userInfo);
}

public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
{
      Console.WriteLine(userInfo);
}

public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
{
      Console.WriteLine(userInfo);
}
```

Any advice is welcome.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

See this [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.messaging),

send(message, dryRun) means `Sends the given message via FCM`.

sendToTopic(topic, payload, options) means `Sends an FCM message to a topic`.See [Send to a topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_to_a_topic) for code samples and detailed documentation.

Comment: Thank you, Alexander. 

So...you are saying that send is sent via FCM but sendToTopic is not via FCM?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.md#message
It appears from this that send also supports notifications to TOPIC.
Thanks for your comments, I will try to get this to work for me.

Comment: If I want to send a notification using a topic, I should use sendToTopic rather than send, right?
Thank you very much. I will mark this as an answer. If you really can, please tell me why the best practice for me is sendToTopic. As it will be evidence.
Thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript registered with Functions was bad.

Bad code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.BucketChanged=functions.region("asia-northeast1").storage.object()
    .onFinalize(async (object)=>{
      const topic = "TopicName";
      const message = {
        topic: topic,
        data: {
          body: object.name,
           contentAvailable: "true",
         },
      };
      admin.messaging().send(message)
          .then((response) => {
            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
           console.log("Error sending message", error);
          });
    }
    );
```

Good code:

```
"use strict";

const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendSilentNotificationWithTopic = functions.region("asia-northeast1")
    .region("asia-northeast1").storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
      const topic = "TopicName";
      const payload = {
        data: {
          imageName: object.name,
        },
      };
      const options = {
        contentAvailable: true,
      };
      return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload, options)
          .then(function(response) {
            return console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            return console.log("Error sending message:", error);
          });
    });
```

Mainly the difference between send and sendToTopic, but can anyone explain why this is happening?
At least I'm getting it right for now....